# SharePoint CSOM: The type of data is different than the one expected

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, csom, pnp-framework

Attempting to access an Office 365 SharePoint online site with the latest CSOM library version gives this error during a file copy operation although it does complete the operation successfully.

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The type of data at position 148 is different than the one expected.
  Source=Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.JsonReader.ReadGuid()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.JsonReader.Read_Guid(JsonReader reader)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.JsonReader.Read[T]()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientResult`1.Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IFromJson.FromJson(JsonReader reader)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.<ExecuteQueryToServerAsync>d__53.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__57.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
   at Program.<Main>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Source\Playground\Program.cs:line 66
```

Here is the response body from the server:

```json
[
  {
    "SchemaVersion": "15.0.0.0",
    "LibraryVersion": "16.0.23710.12002",
    "ErrorInfo": null,
    "TraceCorrelationId": "1dc8b5a0-90d7-3000-a365-ef20f67bed77"
  },
  1,
  null
]
```

NuGet doesn't show any 15.0 versions I can downgrade to.

Comment: Could you share the code, so we can try to reproduce the error.

Comment: I no longer have the code as I was trying different things but I was using the `MoveCopyUtil` provided by the CSOM library which is where it gave the error during that operation of copying a folder to another location. The folder copy operation completed but gave that schema mismatch error. I resolved this issue by using the built-in CopyTo() method in the Pnp.Framework.